# Irreducibility of plane algebraic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties, branched-covers

Given a plane algebraic curve
$$
y^n + a_1(x)y^{n-1} + \dots +a_{n-1}(x) + a_n(x)y = 0,
$$
with a branch point $P_0=(0, y_0)$ of order $n$. Can we prove that this curve is irreducible?
What if the point $P_0$ is singular and unibranch?

Comment: How about $(y-\alpha _1(x))\ldots (y-\alpha _n(x))=0$, with $\alpha _i(0)=0$ for all $i$?

Comment: If by 'unibranch', you mean that the $x$-pre-image in the curve of any sufficiently small punctured disk $D^*_\epsilon = \{ x\ |\ 0<|x|<\epsilon\ \}$ is connected and the $x$-projection is $n$-to-$1$ onto $D^*_\epsilon$, then, yes, the curve is irreducible.

Comment: (Ir)reducibility of the curve depends only on the polynomial (not on a point): it is irreducible iff the polynomial does not factor into a product of non-constant polynomials.

Comment: @abx: The example you gave is singular at $(0, 0)$, but wether it is unibranch?

Comment: @RobertBryant: Thank you very much! I wonder if a unibranch point is a smooth branch point?  In David Mumford's book Algebraic Geometry I, Complex Projective Varieties, on page 43 he defines what is a topologically unibranch:  Let $X$ be an affine variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and $x\in X$. Then $X$ is topologically unibranch at $x$ if for all closed algebraic subsets $Y\subsetneq X$,  $x$ has fundamental system neighborhoods $U_n$ in classical topology of $X$, s.t.  $U_n - (U_n\cup  Y)$ is connected. And he claims that smooth points are topologically unibranch.

Comment: @RobertBryant: I wonder if a smooth branch point is unibranch?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: Thank you for your answer. Someone told me that deciding whether the plane curve is irreducible can be settled if there exists a degree-$n$ projection onto an irreducible curve, with a branch point of order $n$. So I wonder if the algebraic curve projects with degree $n$ onto $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb{C})$ with a branch point of order $n$, implying its irreducibility?

Comment: Yes, this is sufficient for irreducibility.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: Thank you so much.